# Efficient way of marking which elements of a smaller list are in a larger list (Python)

Tags: python, json, list

I am parsing a fairly large dataset from json into a "traditional" data frame (rows as observations, columns as variables). The json object contains a list of characteristics of each observation. I want to transform this into a zero-one vector which indicates whether the observation in question has that characteristic.

What I have is the "master list" (a list of all possible characteristics) and a list of the observations (as json dicts). Let the number of all characteristics be K. The output for each observation should be a zero-one list of length K, marking whether each characteristic applies to that observation.

My current approach is a "brute-force" iteration:

```
characteristics #master list of all possibilities
output_dataset = []

for observation in data:
   chars = observation["characteristics"]
   vector = [ int(chr in chars) for chr in characteristics ]
   output_dataset.append(vector)
```

However, this is rather computationally expensive when the number of characteristics get into the thousands and the number of observations into the tens of thousands.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this (generally, or specifically in Python/Numpy/Pandas)?

**Update:**

For clarity and as an example, here's what the different variables should look like. (Imagine the observations being mobile devices.)

*Master list:* `["android", "ios", "windows", "phone", "tablet", "dual-sim", "fingerprint", "nfc", "usb-c", "lg", "samsung", "huawei", "htc", "motorola", "apple", "google", "nokia"...]`

*One observation:* `["android", "phone", "fingerprint", "nfc", "lg"...]`

*Desired output vector:* `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...]`

Comment: your question is quiet unclear , could elaborate with some examples of your master data set and data ?  from your code, it looks like you are dealing with list of 'strings' ??

Comment: Consider using a `set`.

Comment: I updated the question with an example, hope this will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand this, but I think you want to use a dict. A dict is an efficient way of performing a lookup on an arbitrary key value. Looking up a key in a list of length N is O(N), looking up a key in a dict is optimised by way of a hash table. Depending on the algorithm and the available memory, something  between O(1) and O(ln N).

So, first convert characteristics into a dict which maps a characteristic to an index number, that index numnber being its position in `characteristics`

```
chardict = {}
for i,v in enumerate(characteristics):
    chardict[v] = i
```

and now you have an efficient way to map a characteristic to a `1` in the correct position in your vector

```
vector = [0] * len(characteristics) # initialize all zero, correct length
for k in observation["characteristics"]:
    if  k in chardict: 
        vector[ chardict[k]] = 1
```

It's possibly more efficient to use the `get` method of a dict, and this way you can also check for bad input data, now or later. Less clear, though.

```
L = len(characteristics)
vector = [0] * (L+1)    # last bin for junk input
for k in observation["characteristics"]:
     vector[ chardict.get(k, L) ] = 1

if vector[L]:
    # there was an input not known to characteristics ....

del vector[L]   # get rid of the last element if no longer wanted
```

Comment: Oh man, that was so much faster! Thanks a lot, this helped so much.